# ignoring folder in git, no push and no deploy

Tags: git

We are two people with local repos linked to a remote repo hosted by Gandi. This remote repo gets deployed to a live, browser-accessible location via a Gandi 'deploy' ssh command that I am not sure how it works.

So there are 2 locals, 1 remote, and 1 live repos.

We work in a site that has a cms, and we want the live location to preserve changes done through the cms, those happen within a "content" folder.

So we thought adding the folder to .gitignore in the local repos, then pushing, would leave the content folders of each repo as they are and not push or deploy them.

But it does not seem to wok that way. To stop tracking an already tracked folder, I am told to do the following, and add the folder in gitignore:

```
git rm -r --cached <folder>
```

But apparently, when my collab pulls, his folder WILL be deleted. Which means it will be also deleted in the remote repo, and so deploying it will delete it in the live location I assume.

An alternative seems to be to keep the folder tracked, but ignore further changes with:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <folder>
```

Apparently this needs to be run in mine and my collab local repos. But since the folder is still tracked I assume when deploying the remote repo to live, it will overwrite the content folder.

What we need is for the content folder in each location, 2 locals, 1 remote and particularly 1 live, to be left ALONE AS IT IS. And tell git to not push it at all.

The deploy process may be an important factor here. It is a command by Gandi that I am not sure how it works yet. Meanwhile I would like to understand the git part.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

That shows you the limits of Git alone as a deployment tool.

It is best if you can remove the content folder from your git repo, in order for that folder to be really untouched by any git push command.

As [mentioned in this thread](https://forum.getkirby.com/t/git-commit-and-push-content/2087) though, you can check out [`kirby-git-commit-and-push-content`](https://github.com/blankogmbh/kirby-git-commit-and-push-content)

> a plugin for Kirby that Commits and Pushes Changes made via the Panel to your Git Repository.

---

> I need to push the content folder once to remote then deploy to live; and afterwards completely ignore it everywhere, so we can handle it manually locally and the cms handles it in the live location.
>
> afterwards completely ignore it everywhere,

That is what `git rm -r --cached` will do.
But to avoid subsequent `git pull` delete that folder, replace it by a symlink to a local copy of the content folder *outside* of your repo, and make sure that symlink is ignored in your repo.

Comment: The CMS is Kirby. It is precisely leaving the folder completely untouched what I'd like to do, but don't know how. Help ? thanks

Comment: If " It is precisely leaving the folder completely untouched" (that is "content"), what is the problem? Is is possible to issue a kirby command to trigger the content generation?

Comment: no, I need to push the content folder once to remote then deploy to live; and afterwards completely ignore it everywhere, so we can handle it manually locally and the cms handles it in the live location.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want the folder in your git repo, you should of course definitely (at some point) remove it from your repo.

```
git rm -r --cached <folder>
```

Along with adding the folder to .gitignore, as you've done, is the way to handle the git aspect of things. Once both of those are done, git will not know or care anything about the folder, which is your first goal in regards to git.

I would then proceed this way:

1.) Download the current content fold from your website (via ftp or other tool). Make 100% sure you have backups of the current site.

2.) Push your repo. Depending on the particulars of your deployment tool, doing so may or may not delete the content folder from your site. Some deployment tools completely delete the entire website and re-upload all of the code, others only upload changed files, etc. Whether your live content folder gets deleted has nothing to do with git, only to do with your deployment tool really.

3.) If your deployment tool happens to delete the content folder, simple re-upload it via ftp right away. This would result in a little bit of down time; the downtime will be very brief as long as you are prepared.

4.) Other code collaborators can also download the content folder, put it in their git repo so they can work locally, and git will ignore it because it is in .gitignore

After doing this you'll be able to push your repo and the content folder will be left alone, assuming your deployment tool does not delete it.

A note though, **this is not really a best practice**. Best practice is that all code on a server is *always* in your git repository, other than maybe files that are built/compiled. Why? Well, what if your server gets completely fried? Your server gets corrupted, destroyed in a fire, etc.? If that happens, and the content was not in your git repo or a recent backup on *a different* server...you have lost all of your content forever. What if you start getting a lot of traffic and need two servers to handle the extra load? If all the code is in your repo, you can create start a new server ("spin up" if you want the real lingo), push your code to it, and you can be 100% sure it will have the exact same contents as your first server.

I think your next question would be: well I need remote developers to be able to edit the content folder, so they can try things out locally. The best way to do that is to use *branches* and *pull requests*. Anytime a developer wants to deploy code to your live site, force them (Bitbucket and Github allow you to require pull requests on a branch, meaning no direct edits to the branch can be made) to use a pull request. You then review all pull requests, and make sure no changes to the content folder have been made. If you DO want to change the content on the live site, then first make the change in your local repo, test the changes, and then push/deploy to your live site! Maybe you have someone who is a blog post writer who does most of the content changes? Create a special branch for them; they can make all the changes they want to, then you merge that branch into master and deploy it to the live site.

Sorry, many edits and a lot of writing. Another good option for you may be to put the content folder into its own repo. Remote developers can pull from this repo, but not push changes. Your blog writer/content creator is the only one that can push changes to it (Bitbucket allows this, I assume Github does too). You may have to configure your deployment tool a bit to push both repositories to specific locations, but this is also a good option.

And finally, the best option in my opinion -- use a CMS that stores things in a database :) This is precisely what a database is supposed to be used for, in my opinion. Web servers should be completely disposable, and in fact for sites that get a lot of traffic, must be; we must be able to spin up multiple servers all with the exact same code in order to handle the traffic, and all of these servers get their "dynamic content" so to speak from a database.